# Two controllers on a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

i'm creating a directive that will have methods that the children will access. But at the same time i'm requiring 'form' on my directive.

```
return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            object: '='
        },
        require: 'form',
        controller: function ($scope, $element) {
            this.hi = function () {
                console.log('i am here')
            }
        },
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, controllers) {
            console.log(controllers);
        }
    }
```

I've always thought that if i was goign to use two controllers, they would be in one array. But when i log them, i only get the FormController:

[image: Log that i've received on console]

What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the syntax for require is a little different in the docs. Have you played around with that? e.g. `require: ['^form']`

Not sure how to specify your other controller in there, but perhaps in this way it might show up as an array?